# Scanf is being ignored

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define length 20
main()
{
    float x;
    int y;
    float array1[length], array2[length], array3[length];
    float ray[length];
    int size1 = insert(array1, length);
    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    int size2 = insert(array2, length);
    int size3 = insert(array3, length);
}

int insert(float a[], int size)
{
    int  n = 0;
    while(n<size && scanf("%f\n", &a[n]) == 1)
    {
        printf("you entered: ");
        printf("%2.1f\n", a[n]);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

When I run the program, it executes the first insert okay, but the next time function is called, `scanf()` seems to be ignored completely. I tried putting it right after where insert is done, but that's ignored as well.

Comment: Please indent&format your code properly.

Comment: 1) How do you know it is ignored?

Comment: @Olaf Not a duplicate, yet that accepted answer does solve this post.

Comment: @user3121023 it will still ignore that scanf still

Comment: @user3121023 yes I did

Comment: put spaces before and after %f and %d in every scanf

Comment: `scanf(" %d ", &y);`  ...  `scanf(" %f ", &a[n])`

Comment: it will still see scanf == 0 after inputting a character

Comment: Your definition of `main()` indicates that you are using a very old book or compiler.

Comment: What means "the first time"? The first time calling `scanf` or the first time `insert()` with multiple successful `scanf`? What do you enter that `insert()` terminates? If you terminate the input completely, don't wonder that there is no input anymore in further calls... A little dump of the console output would be helpful

Comment: 1
you entered: 1.0
enter new number
2
you entered: 2.0
enter new number
3
you entered: 3.0
enter new number
4
you entered: 4.0
enter new number
5
you entered: 5.0
enter new number
6
you entered: 6.0
enter new number
k
enter number: after inserting a non-number it will stop

Comment: do not use `scanf`. Get the whole line with `fgets` and the parse it with `sscanf`. You have much more control with these two functions

Comment: @sajax63 you should show the unexpected output in the question, instead of as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use %*c in scanf to consume the newlines along with space around %d in the scanf in main(). I tested the below code on MingW and it seem to work. The '\n' in your scanf is being consumed making it scanf() return while the '\n' at the press of enter key still remains in IO buffer to be consumed by scanf() again; hence the weird behaviour.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define length 20

int insert(float *a, int size)
{
    int  n = 0;
    while(n<size && scanf("%f%*c", &a[n]))
    {
        printf("you entered: ");
        printf("%2.1f\n", a[n]);
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
float x;
    int y;
    float array1[length], array2[length], array3[length];
    float ray[length];
    int size1 = insert(array1, length);
    printf("enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    int size2 = insert(array2, length);
    int size3 = insert(array3, length);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Why? I did quick run on DevC++ and it doesn't complain.

Comment: @M.M Works fine with that as well.

Comment: Cool, will remove my comments now that it is fixed

Answer (score 0):

In the `scanf` format string, change `"%f\n"` to `"%f"`.  The `\n` in a scanf format string does not mean "wait for newline".

You do not need to worry about waiting for newline, because the only format specifiers you use are `%f` and `%d`, which both discard any leading whitespace.